# fgets is not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

`fgets` is not working as I expected.

```
typedef struct {
    int itemnumber;
    char name [50];
    double price;
    int stock;
    int discount;
    int reorder;
    int reorderquantity;
} item;


item x;
item *px[n];
px[n] = malloc(sizeof(item));

printf ("ENTER THE NUMBER OF ITEMS\n\n");
scanf ("%d",&n);


for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    px[i]=&x;
    scanf ("%d",&px[i]->itemnumber);
    fgets(px[i]->name,50,stdin);
    px[i]->name[strlen(px[i]->name)-1]='\0';
    // fflush(stdin);
    printf("%s",px[i]->name);
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to a more fundamental question, rather than posting the entire code for what appears to be a homework assignment?

Comment: I can't see any malloc or fget calls in the code...

Comment: "i am not sure exactly what the malloc() is really for" - Google?

Comment: The `fgets()` is 'not working' (as you expected) because the `scanf()` for a number leaves a newline behind which is read by the `fgets()`.  You need to check each input function (`fgets()` and `scanf()` to ensure that they found what they were looking for.  Remember that `fgets()` includes the newline in the string it returns (unless there isn't space for it in the string, in which case it is left in the input stream for the next I/O operation).

Comment: `px[n] = malloc(sizeof(item));` n is off by one here. BTW: _what_ is n ?

Comment: n is suppose to be the number of items

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Don't worry if your first question isn't the ideal one, most first questions aren't. Try to find the criticism here as a good thing and learn with it instead of got mad with those people.

Comment: After editing your question, I would start looking for the question, and then afterwards posting on SO. The question is not well defined - instead you are doing a lot of questions on it. Work on letting clear exactly what you want to learn.

Comment: You've asked four questions in this question. *Ask one question per question posted*; if you have four questions then *please post four questions*.

Comment: i am sorry for that this is my first post @EricLippert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only malloc one instance.
you should do px[n] = malloc(sizeof(item)*n); after you scanf n